# Set default colors to Android library

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-theme, android-custom-attributes

So I have an Android [library](https://github.com/shem8/MaterialLogin) that I want others to be able to easily customize its color when using it. The problem is that the color is not just a single property (like the view background), but it's more like a theme color (the view background, the text color, the stroke for the button, etc...) so I'm not able to just pass it as a view attribute. So I ended up using a `color reference` and use it in styles, layout and drawables:

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="color" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/color">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/color"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/LibraryTheme.TextAppearance"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml in library project:

```
<style name="LibraryTheme.TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?attr/color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?attr/color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">?attr/color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">?attr/color</item>
</style>
```

That works great, and when someone is using my lib he **must** declare the color he wants you use in his theme:

styles.xml in app project:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="color">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

The problem is this: I want to deliver this library with a default color scheme. It can be performed now with 2 options:

1. Declare my own theme with the default color sets and the user will need to inherit his theme from mine.
2. Put some default_color in my color.xml so that the user will be able to use that as the color in his theme.

The first one is really bad, because I can't force the user to use specific app theme (like AppCompact.Light).
The second one is not that great either, because I want the user to be able to use the default seamlessly and I have a couple of colors in the theme that he needs to set.

Is there any other way that you think I will be able to let other users play with the colors easily?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check [SublimePicker](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker) project's [theme](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker/blob/master/sublimepickerlibrary/src/main/res/values/themes.xml) setup. It is quite complex since I had to provide a lot of theming options. From your categorization, this setup would fall under **1**, I think. `The first one is really bad, cause I can't force the user to use specific app theme (like AppCopact.Light)` --- No, you would be asking the user to override _your_ theme, like `parent="MyLibrarysDefaultTheme"`. This is okay.

Comment: @Vikram looks like you used all the style attribute as single properties and just set them in the code (like `iconColor`), what if I have color in multiple places that some of them can't be set in code?

Comment: What you need is control over what attributes are set, and what to do when they are not present/invalid. This control can only be afforded when you create custom components. In your specific case, you would check whether `attr/color` has been set, and if not, use a default value - at _runtime_. Another thing that you should keep in mind is that users (or rather clients) of your product will be developers - not end users. It is alright to impose a requirement if it does not take anything away from the library's core functionality.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you are using a color reference, in your case I would use a regular color property- those can be overridden by the user in colors.xml.

So in you library project:

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="color">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/color"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/LibraryTheme.TextAppearance"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="LibraryTheme.TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color</item>
</style>
```

And if the user wants to use different colors, he can declare his own color in his app's colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="color">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the color is kinda overriden for the one specified in the app resources file.

Comment: I have been doing this but I got into a situation where one of my user has requirement to change the theme based on logged in user type. Now color cannot be changed in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I get the point correctly but I guess you have the following option:

Declare in your Strings.xml file something like this:

```
<!-- Colors-->
    <color name="color1">#55000000</color>
    <color name="color2">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="color3">#000000</color>
```

And then customize your template objects passing this reference. If the user wants to change all the app colors, he needs just to set new values in String.xml

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/color1"/>
```

Comment: The TextView is in the library, so the user can't put the color there

Comment: Man, I did not get you. This user that you refer is a programmer or someone with the app installed?

Comment: Sorry, will try to make it more clear- the user is a programmer that want to use the library. But the only thing he needs to do is the put the <LoginCustomView/> in his layout (the text view and all is inside the library code)

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick to option 1. As a theme is only a collection of attributes, I don't see how you "force" the user to inherit your theme - he only needs to supply the list of attributes, plus he has something working to start with...